# Vue workbox, dont cache specific dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, service-worker, workbox

How can I disable certain routes from getting cached by the service worker? 
Eg I have a URL: https://someurl.com/emailValidate/1231231?email=some@email.com - The thing after emailValidate is a dynamic ID, which is why I dont want all things on the route /emailValidate and after that should not be cached by the SW...

I've tried adding this to the vue.config, but doesnt seem to do much:

```
module.exports = {
pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
        swSrc: './src/sw.js',
        swDest: 'service-worker.js',
        globIgnores: ['**/emailValidate', '**/passwordReset']
    },
    runtimeCaching: [
        {
            urlPattern: new RegExp('/emailValidate'),
            handler: 'NetworkFirst'
        },
        {
            urlPattern: new RegExp('/passwordReset'),
            handler: 'NetworkFirst'
        }
    ],
    navigateFallbackBlacklist: ['/emailValidate', '/passwordReset']
}
```

};